Does the new image uploader keep track of the uploader identity (i.e., who uploaded what)?
I wonder the following: Does the new image uploader keep track of the uploader identity (i.e., who uploaded what)?

If I look at network traffic I only see cloudflare cookies being send/set and those are not long lived. If there is tracking I doubt it is by means of client-side stuff. Worth mentioning that uploading images always passed through SE servers, and they know who you are, if not directly then at least by taking the network logging and stitch all the calls together.

Images would be (generally) embedded in a post/comment so it would be a minor amount of effort to find where an image is being referenced on-site.

With our new image hosting service, we do keep track of who uploaded which image, connecting it to the user ID / account ID of the person who uploaded it. We do this because we want a Data Subject Request (DSR) from a user to be able to cover images they've uploaded as appropriate, including their profile image(s). In the case of a request to delete a user's account, we also want to be able to delete that user's profile image(s).
We may have other legal reasons for utilizing this data as well, which may be difficult to comprehensively predict, but will likely include copyright infringement or other forms of network abuse.
